# upload csv into mysql only if unique name (create if not exist)

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, pdo

trying to do and upload csv script and hitting an error that doesn't make sense.  invalid token. It says my columns don't match my ?,?,?,?,?. 5 columns, 5 ? question marks, what did I miss?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        <input name="row_name" type="text">
  </form>
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"; //Data Source Name = Mysql
(isset($rowname = $_POST['row_name']));
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password); //Connect to DB
$do = $db->prepare(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $username.$rowname (
         id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
         list_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
         fname char(60),
         lname char(60),
         list_email varchar(100),
         PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )
        CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
        TRUNCATE TABLE $username.$rowname
        INSERT INTO $username.$rowname VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
        );
$csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        $do->execute($data);
        var_dump($data);}
    fclose($handle);}
exit( "Complete!" );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/wemail1/www/pages/campaign-build.inc.php on line 58
```

Sample data:

```
fname, lname, email
joe, schmoe, bogus@bogus.com
mary, lamb, hoe@us.com
```

Comment: For starters, figure out where both "$username" and "$rowname" are *supposed* to be defined, and verify that they *are* being defined.  Update your post with the relevant code if you still have questions about that part.

Comment: $username is defined via require_once('auth.php'); which I removed for simplicity. No issues with $username. and $rowname = $_POST['row_name']

Comment: @Jason I don't think  Mysqli::bind_param()   is PDO compatible

Comment: You're right, I've been looking at so many MySqli questions I didn't even look. @brad Can we see the sample csv?

Comment: @Jason I tried 2 thru 7 question marks. It's something else. the question marks are supposed to match the number of fields or imported data?

Comment: Your sample data out of the csv shows three columns, but you bind for five.  `INSERT INTO $username.$rowname (fname, lname, email) VALUES (?,?,?)` might be more successful, but there's more to it I suspect.

Comment: Yeah, it will need to match exactly when you do not specify column names to insert. Ross's suggestion should work. If you have 5 fields but 3 values to insert, you'll need to specify them or add the two values to $data before you execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $data hasn't got 5 params. And this is what say the error message too. You have 3 value, and the code want 5 value. You need something like this:

```
$insert = array(NULL, $data[0]." ".$data[1], $data[0],$data[1],$data[2]);
$do->execute($insert);
```

Instead of:

```
$do->execute($data);
```

So, If you have 5 ? in your prepare, you need an array which have 5 values, or you got that error.